# PostgreSQL automatically create column from existing table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgreSQL and I would like to automatically insert the value of `username` from table `users` in the `profiles` table as `handle` when i create a new user.

Is this possible by means of an SQL statement?

For clearifing:

First i add a new user:

`insert into users (email, user_name, first_name, last_name, active, created_at) values ('john@doe.com', 'johndoe', 'John', 'Doe', true, '2018-03-16T17:39:54Z');`

After that i create a profile for this user:

`insert into profiles (user_id, handle, name, city) VALUES (2, 'johndoe', 'John Doe', 'Tawala');`

With this step, the value of `user_name` should be automatically written to the `handle` column in the `profiles` table without doing so manually. 
Are there solutions like a function in SQL?

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id serial UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  user_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  first_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  active bool DEFAULT TRUE,
  created_at DATE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profiles (
  id serial UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  user_id serial NOT NULL,
  handle varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  city varchar(255) NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON 
  UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Do you want a new row in `profiles` to be created whenever there is an `INSERT` on `users`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The row `handle` exists in `profiles` when i create the new user.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. Can you clarify that.

Comment: I will  write it in the questions. give me a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may combine them using a `WITH` clause `INSERT`

```
with ins1
AS
(
  insert into users (email, user_name, first_name, last_name, active, created_at) 
   values ('john@doe.com', 'johndoe', 'John', 'Doe', true, '2018-03-16T17:39:54Z')
       returning id as ret_user_id, user_name as ret_user_name 
 )      
  insert into profiles (user_id, handle, name, city) 
     select ret_user_id, ret_user_name ,'John Doe', 'Tawala' 
from ins1; --takes from the returning output.
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=81bafb4ad68f6424b69a45e0bac4c2c9)

Comment: Thanks, that helps me doing what i want ;)